# How to imitate Bootstrap's html code highlighting and copy to clipboard?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, copy, clipboard, codehighlighter

I really like the getting started guide by Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/), and I want to do something similar in my project. I've looked at highlight.js but it seems the color is a bit off to me. I don't know how to implement the copy to clipboard feature. Is this something I should be able to come up with on my own? I prefer third party solutions since this isn't the main crux of my project, but I thought this will be nice to my users.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving highlight.js another look.  There are multiple style themes you can choose from if you find the color to be off on a particular one.  Or, you can do a little css to customize the colors yourself.

An alternative for syntax highlighting is [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/).

For the copy to clipboard piece, take a look at [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard).